# How can I highlight multiple variables in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse, if you rest your cursor on a variable it will highlight that variable everywhere in the code.  I was wondering how you could highlight more than one variable at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but using the find dialog you can look for two variables in the same search.

1. Mark the Regular Expressions Checkbox in the Options.
2. Use a regular expression in the Find textbox. For example if you are looking both for the `index` and `count` variables use `(index)|(count)`.
3. The Find button will cycle through all instances of both `index` and `count`.

This can be expanded to even more tricky searches.